# Laravel 5.2 migration foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I am new to web development in Laravel 5.2 and I have this problem.
I have a Users and Jobseekers tables and  I am trying to create a foreign key in the Jobseekers table that references the Users table using migration but when I run 
php artisan migrate I get the error

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key cons
  traint fails (`jobsitelara`.`#sql-1a04_7d`, CONSTRAINT `jobseekers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`
  ) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `jobseekers` add constraint jobseekers_user_id_foreign fore
  ign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key cons
  traint fails (`jobsitelara`.`#sql-1a04_7d`, CONSTRAINT `jobseekers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`
  ) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

Here is the migration for create_users_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and the migration for create_jobseekers_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobseekers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->enum('gender',array('male','female'));
            $table->date('dateofbirth');
            $table->string('occupation', 150);
            $table->string('educationlevel', 200);
            $table->string('cv', 150);
            $table->string('skills', 200);
            $table->string('address', 200);
            $table->string('phonenumber', 30);
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and the migration to create the foreign key is in a separate file that runs after the create tables migrations have been run
here is the add_foreignkey_to_jobseekers_table migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('jobseekers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

I made sure that the user_id field in the Jobseekers table is also unsigned.
I noticed that the tables are referenced as **jobsitelara'.'#sql-1a04_8f'** in the error messages, I don't understand what's going on.
What else is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel Database Migrations**, you need to have clear the order of your migrations and the **parent – child** relationship between your tables. Therefore, when you create tables, you need to create parent tables **first** and **then** child tables.

In the Other hand, when you delete tables, you need to delete child tables **first** and **then** parents.

[@Martin Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102205/martin-bean) has an explanation on this topic [What is a Parent table and a Child table in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102205/martin-bean).

When you run in your terminal **php artisan migrate**:  **--options--**, your functions **up** and **down** will be called respectively depending on the option you pass to migrate. If you order your migrations having parent-child relationships clear, you won’t have this problem.

There are also other situations that you should consider when designing your database, like recursive relationships between tables which [@Branko Dimitrijevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533120/branko-dimitrijevic) explains in this topic [Database design for a recursive relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533120/branko-dimitrijevic).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobseekers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->enum('gender',array('male','female'));
            $table->date('dateofbirth');
            $table->string('occupation', 150);
            $table->string('educationlevel', 200);
            $table->string('cv', 150);
            $table->string('skills', 200);
            $table->string('address', 200);
            $table->string('phonenumber', 30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


public function up()
{
    Schema::table('jobseekers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Remove user_id string from the  create_jobseekers_table and put following foreign key table code on add_foreignkey_to_jobseekers_table